# JS alert pop up when id="something"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code that has a ID that is question-number, each time I click my button it goes up numbers.

I am trying to write a small script that will show a model or a alert box once the id prints on page

> "Question 2 of 40"

I so far have

**CODE**

```
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column-left">
                    <div id="question-number" class="question-text"></div>
                    <div id="question-time" class="question-time"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**what I have tried**

**First attempt**

```
<script>
                function myFunction() {

                    var content =('#question-number').html();

                    if (content.indexOf("Question 2 of 40") != -1) {
                        alert("String Found");
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

**Second attempt**

```
<script>
                    if($('#test-view').attr('question-number').indexOf('Question 2 of 40') != -1) {
                        alert('here !!!');
                    }
                </script>
```

Any one see why either of these attempts do not work ?

UPDATE

I just need a scrip that says if see

> Question 2 of 40

on DOM the alert box

Comment: Assuming you set the text of `question-number` programmatically, you be much better served by raising an event and listening for that to happen

Comment: `if ($('#question-number').text() == "Question 2 of 40") alert('found!');`

Comment: in your first try, you're missing a dollar sign for your selector and in the second try, your selector doesn't select anything as there is no element with id "test-view"

Comment: Ok thanks guys, ill try these and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is nearly working

You forgot `$` in the first line.

if you just declare the function without calling it, it will never work

```js
var content = $('#question-number').html();

if (content.indexOf("Question 2 of 40") !== -1) {
  alert("String Found");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column-left">
    <div id="question-number" class="question-text">Question 2 of 40</div>
    <div id="question-time" class="question-time"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't know when to run. You need to add the following:

```
$(function(){ //need this line to wait for document to be ready before binding to click event.
    $('#question-number').on('click', function(){
        //your code here
    }
});
```

Or

```
<div id="question-number" class="question-text" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
```

I would also check into learning how to use your browser developer tools. They will help you immensely when you have problems like this.

Comment: Hmm not working yet, what browser developer tools would your recommend ?

Comment: If you right click in chrome or IE, you should see an "Inspect" link. Click that and browse to the "sources" tab in chrome or "debugger" tab in IE. You should then be able to navigate to your code and set break points on your javascript. The "console" tab should also tell you what kind of errors you are getting.

Comment: yes, i know and have been using console for many years, no errors. thanks anyways.

Comment: can you provide a plunker or fiddle? I could probably help more if I could play with the code